# Android documentation differs from Android Studio warning

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, code-documentation

I'm currently implementing an **AlertDialog** in which there is a **CheckBox**. In order to do that, I inflate a view containing a **CheckBox** and then I add it to my Dialog using the `setView(View)` method, but by proceeding that way I get huge padding. From what I read, a solution to that problem would apparently be to use the `setView(View, int, int, int, int)` method (which sets the padding for all direction) instead, but when I try to implement that android studio gives me an error (that can be avoided by adding `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` but I don't know what that does nor means, so if you know don't hesitate to explain to me) and then says that this method is deprecated, the weird thing is that in the documentation (right [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View))), there is nothing saying that this method is deprecated, so I would like to know, in these kinds of moment, should I trust the documentation or androidStudio? (and also if it is a good idea to use the second method)

here is the code of the **AlertDialog** :

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View checkBoxView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.checkbox, null);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_dontaskmeagain);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            SharedPrefUtils.setShowAlertDialog(getContext(), b);
        }
    });

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.alert_everyday_dialog_message);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_title)
            .setView(checkBoxView, 0, 0, 0, 0) //this apparently is deprecated
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mListener.onEverydayDialogPositiveClick(DeleteTaskEverydayDialog.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mListener.onEverydayDialogNegativeClick(DeleteTaskEverydayDialog.this);
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Note that this is a custom class that extends from AlertDialog in which there are some other functions but I don't think that they are needed, if you think so, tell me and I'll provide them

Comment: Do you get padding from top only?

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan no actually the padding is only on top and below

Comment: Can you please provide the code where you are building `AlertDialog` ?

Comment: `AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
 alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 return builder.create();`
Try to replace this code with the last line.

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan this doesn't change anything;

Comment: Yes,sorry then I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong docs - namely `AlertDialog`. The code you are calling is on `AlertDialog.Builder`. It does not have any docs since it is annotated with `@hide` and thus excluded from SDK and its documentation. It also has `@RestrictTo` and `@Deprecated` annotations as seen in the [support library source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/caf984504c497e04280a61f53fcf92fdb7989391/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.java#L908).

Some rationale for hiding is given in the javadoc:

> This is currently hidden because it seems like people should just be able to put padding around the view.

Generally speaking, you should not be calling hidden or restricted methods. Find some other way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know anything about that, very instructive thanks a lot